# SESSION variable not transmitted over other site

Tags: php, variables, session, session-variables

I have two pages on my webapp, both accessable with the same domain. They are in different folders. Both use Sessions, but the second page cant access the session.

I cant realy understand why...

Here are the first lines of my site:

The page where I create create all session variables (the `login.php`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
...
...
```

The page where the session isnt transmitted to (the `image.php`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['general_email']) || $_SESSION['orga_ang'] != 1) {
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=login.php? 
 src=account.php'>";
 die();
}
...
...
```

As I said, both sites are accessable under the same domain, but the site where I create the login is in a different folder, the route from the `login.php` to the `image.php` is `../assets/modules/images/showimage.php`

Why cant I access the session variable in my `image.php` ?

oOn other pages I can access the $_SESSION variable, only on `image.php` not.

Comment: what's the path of the session cookie?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should have `session_start()` before anything has been output, so move `<!DOCTYPE html>` to after your first PHP tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call session_start before any other output including your doctype statement. Change

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
```

to

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove any output before session_start() in image php

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['general_email']) || $_SESSION['orga_ang'] != 1) {
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=login.php? src=account.php'>";
  die();
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know what happens always you can use error reports function.

```
error_reporting(1)
```

BTW. Twat is this ?

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=login.php?src=account.php'>";
```

Mean:

```
?src=account.php
```

Comment: I use this as redicret. If a user isnt logged in, I know where the user was and after he logged in I send him back to where he was.

Comment: Better way is use `header('location: file_to_redirect.php?arrg');`